# What is best practice method of checking for user accessible elements in a website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I can think of a couple of ways of achieving this (presuming for websites hosted on a Windows machine):

A) JavaScript side: Storing the authenticated user's accessibility role (e.g. Admin, Demo-User, ...etc) and basically rendering (or not rendering or disabling) relevant html elements/controls based on this role.

B) MVC side: Where the explanation in [A] is basically done on IIS and thus the views which are rendered via .CSHTML are manipulated based on the user's Role.

C) Combination of [A] & [B]: This is the most likely case.

Please, I would like the community's professional and experienced input on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only use approach A, however in a different way.

As I use default simple membership in my apps, I just add some roles into the DB and add appropriate users to those roles.

Then, for filtering contents, I just do two jobs:

1) I filter controller request to appropriate roles by use of `[Authorize]` attrib:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "role1, role2, ...")]
```

2) I create a partial view to render the navigation bar/main menu. In that view, I first retrieve the roles of the current user:

```
var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

Then, according to his/her roles, I render menu items:

```
bool hasRole1 = roles.Contain("role1") | roles.Contain("admin");
// ...
@if (hasRole1)
{
    <li>...</li>
}
```